# Infinite Products of Categories

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, definition

$\newcommand{A}{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand{B}{\mathcal{B}}
\newcommand{C}{\mathcal{C}}
\newcommand{T}{\mathsf{T}}$

The product of two categories $\A$ and $\B$ is the category $\A \times\B$ with objects being pairs $(A,B)$, having $A \in \A$ and $B \in \B$, and morphism similarly defined by pairs of appropriate morphisms. This definition simply extends to $n$-arry products.

It also seems that there is a simple extension to a family of categories $\C_i$ indexed  by the set $I$. Category $ \prod_{i \in I}\C $ should have dependend functions $X : I \to \C_i, X : i \mapsto X_i$ as objects with evident morphisms. What concerns me here is consistence of certain $\infty$-variable Galois connections.

For example,  for every topological space it is possible $X$ to define small order category $\T X$ with open sets as objects, and morphisms corresponding to the relationship $(\subseteq)$. Evidently, if we use above definition of the product  of categories for the infinite set $I$, and product topology defined by natural property for the product of topological spaces, then:

$$ \prod_{i \in I} \T X_i \not\subseteq \T\prod_{i \in I} X_i $$

in general, as topology on $\prod_{i \in I} X_i$ will be generated by products of open sets $\prod_{i\in I}U_i$ with only finite number of $U_i \neq X_i$. This is bad as results in topology and measure theory involving infinite products may not translate well to the categorical language.

To overcome this issue I propose **definition of special product of categories**, $\prod^\wedge_{i \in I} \C_i$ with dependent functions as above for objects, but with only finite number of values **not being terminal**, or dually $\prod^\vee_{i \in I} \C_i$ with only finite number of values **not being initial**.  Probably, this type of products need to be define only for categories with these universal objects. Finite products will be equal to normal products. Furthermore, any motphisms will be defined by a finite number of arrows from original categories.

In my example, then
$$
 {\prod_{i \in I}}^\wedge \T X_i \subseteq \T \prod_{i \in I} X_i,
$$

and in fact $\prod_{i \in I}^\wedge \T X_i$ is the base for the topology of $\prod_{i \in I} X_i$.

Probably such definitions of products only may make sense in more narrow order theory of even lattice theory. I haven"t seen anything like this defined before.

> Are non-standard products of categories like these used somewhere (Not necessarily exactly like these)? Сan you provide a reference if that is a case?

Thank you for reading this long question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that your construction should be something similar (i.e. equivalent if not isomorphic to the following).

Let $(\mathbf C_i)_{i \in I}$ be a family of categories with a terminal object. Then we have a natural diagram $D$ parametrized by the posetetal category of finite subsets of $I$, this diagram associates

- to each finite subset $J \subseteq I$ the category $\prod_{i \in J}\mathbf C_i$
- to each inclusion $J_1 \subseteq J_2$ the natural embedding $\prod_{i \in J_1} \mathbf C_i \to \prod_{i \in J_2} \mathbf C_i$.

The colimit of this diagram should provides your special product.

Note that this is basically the direct-sum construction for rings and modules (over a fixed ring), in the last case this construction is also the coproduct, and it should specialize in the case of $\mathbf {Lex}$ to the coproduct described by **ne-**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @NikPronko yep, sorry for the typo.

Comment: I accepted your answer because of vox populi

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a reference, but your construction appears to come up when thinking about infinite coproducts in the category $\mathrm{Lex}$ with

- Objects: small categories with finite limits,
- Morphisms: functors that preserve finite limits.

(By Gabriel-Ulmer duality, it would also come up when thinking about infinite products in the category of locally finitely presentable categories; you might be able to find references along these lines.)

I claim that if $(\mathcal{C}_i)_{i\in I}$ is a collection of objects in $\mathrm{Lex}$, then their categorical coproduct $\coprod_{i\in I}^{\mathrm{Lex}} \mathcal{C}_i$ is exactly the full subcategory $\prod_{i\in I}^{\wedge}\mathcal{C}_i$ of the product category consisting of those sequence $(c_i)_{i\in I}$ where $c_i$ is terminal for all but finitely many $i\in I$. Observe first that $\prod_{i\in I}^{\wedge}\mathcal{C}_i$ lives in $\mathrm{Lex}$ (whereas the coproduct $\coprod_{i\in I}^{\mathrm{Cat}}\mathcal{C}_i$ does not). Moreover, given maps $f_i\colon \mathcal{C}_i\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ in $\mathrm{Lex}$, we obtain a unique map $f\colon \prod_{i\in I}^{\wedge}\mathcal{C}_i\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$ in $\mathrm{Lex}$ given by $f((c_i)_{i\in I}) = \prod_{i\in I}f_i(c_i)$; this product exists as most $f_i(c_i)$ are terminal.

Comment: Thanks, This is interesting. I need to think it over a bit more.